# Php string split, how can i do that?

Tags: php, parsing, split

```
$mystring = "@blablabla Kayit Ol ogrencino:1176160"
```

This is my string, `placament of ogrencino:1176160` in string can change, but others will be stable.

Like:

```
$mystring = "@blablabla ogrencino:1176160 Kayit Ol" etc.
```

How can i parse `"1176160"`?

Comment: Are they the only numbers? `$number = preg_replace("/\D/","",$input);`

Comment: they are but, it can be "@blablabla 15 Kayit Ol ogrencino:1176160" too. Sorry i didnt clarify myself... I must take after ogrencino: but only numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at this regex:

```
(?<=ogrencino:)(.+?)[\s$]
```

It is independent of what value exists after `ogrencino:`. (It can be digit or non-digit)

Regex break up:

```
(?<=ogrencino:) = Positive look behind, checks `ogrencino:` exists behind the next criteria.
.+?             = Any thing (except new line) one or more time, but lazy due to `?`.
[\s$]           = after match either whitespace or end of line will exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match` like so:

```
$mystring = "@blablabla ogrencino:1176160 Kayit Ol";

// Changed regular expression to match Kolink's comment
preg_match('/(?<=\bogrencino:)\d+/', $mystring, $matches);

print_r($matches);
// displays Array ( [0] => 1176160 )
```

If it appears more than once in the string you can do `preg_match_all()`

Comment: +1 It would be better if you also add some explanation to it :)

Comment: Since only the numbers are needed, `/(?<=\bogrencino:)\d+/` would be a better regex.

Comment: @Kolink Thank you for the better expression.  I'm kind of a novice when it comes to regex.

Comment: What if they wont only numbers ? Can i still use it ?

Comment: No you can't use this regular expression if you want to get non-numeric values.  If you want to get something other than numbers you need to find a new terminator. So if for example the string will always have a space after it then we can use that

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into regular expressions, particularly [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

For your specific example do something like this:

```
$mystring = "@blablabla ogrencino:1176160 Kayit Ol";
$matches = array();
preg_match( '/ogrencino\d+/', $mystring, $matches);

echo $matches[0];  // ogrencino:1176100
```

What this does is find every instance of "one or more digits" (that's what the `\d+` is) and read every match into `$matches`

Answer (score 0):

Without REGEX:

```
$string = "@blablabla ogrencino:1176160 Kayit Ol";
$beg = strpos($string,"ogrencino:") + strlen("ogrencino:");
$end = strpos($string," ",$beg);
$mynumber = substr($string,$beg,$end-$beg); //1176100
```